# Kendogrid Cascading DropdownList using Editor functions

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-grid

I am using kendo Grid Editor functions for implementing a cascading DropDownList for Country & State in Popup(Edit Form). But i am unable to do that(Both Lists are populated successfully but they are not cascaded. Like when user selects Country option the State List should be populated on the basis of country option selected). Please help me. I have tried many solution from Telerik Website but they are using arrays, Odata as their DataSource. I am getting data from Database.

Here is my Code

Controller:

```
      public JsonResult Details()
      {

     var country = dbforcountry.Countries.ToLoist();
     list<SelectListItems> licountry = new list<SelectListItems>();
     foreach (var i in country)
     {
     licountry .Add(new list<SelectListItems> {Text = u.Name, Value = 
     u.ID.ToString() } );
     }

     return Json(new SelectList(licountry, "Value", "Text",        
     JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet))

     }

     public JsonResult getstates(int id)
     {

      var states= dbforcountry.States.ToLoist();
      list<SelectListItems> listates = new list<SelectListItems>();
      foreach (var i in states) 
      {
      listates.Add(new list<SelectListItems> {Text = u.Name, Value = 
      u.ID.ToString() } );
      }

      return Json(new SelectList(listates, "Value", "Text", 
      JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet))

      }
```

Editor Function (View):

```
       function CountryDropDown(container, options)
       {
       $('<input id="Countrydropdown" data-text-field="Text" data-value-
       field="Value" data-bind="value:'+options.field+'" />')
       .appendTo(container)
       .kendDropDownList({

        autoBind: false,
        dataTextField="Text", 
        dataValueField="Value",
        dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport:{
        read:{
          url: "../mycontroller/Details",
          method:"POST"
            }
           }
          },
          })
          }

        function StateDropDown(container, options)
        {
        $('<input id="Statedropdown" data-text-field="Text" data-value-
        field="Value" data-bind="value:'+options.field+'" />')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendDropDownList({

         autoBind: false,
         dataTextField="Text", 
         dataValueField="Value",
         dataSource: {
         type: "json",
         transport:{
         read:{
          url: "../mycontroller/getstates",
          method:"POST"
            }
           }
           },
           })
           }
           }

           })
           }
```

Comment: When you say you are "unable to do that", what do you mean? Drop downs are not populating? Controller methods are not being called? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Both are populated successfully. But they are not cascaded. Like when user selects Country option then State Dropdown Should be populated on the basis of Country option selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the [`cascadeFrom`](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist) tag on `StateDropDown`.

```
$('<input id="Statedropdown" data-text-field="Text" data-value-
    field="Value" data-bind="value:'+options.field+'" />')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendDropDownList({
         autoBind: false,
         cascadeFrom: "Countrydropdown", 
         dataTextField="Text", 
         dataValueField="Value",
         dataSource: {
             type: "json",
                 transport:{
                    read:{
                        url: "../mycontroller/getstates",
                        method:"POST"
                    }
             }
         },
     });
```

Note: If you are cascading drop downs through editors, (possibly through a grid control) you can find examples of how to [cascade drop downs within a grid](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/cascading-dropdown-editors).

**EDIT**

If the Telerik solution is not feasible, another solution for chaining two drop downs (i.e. the selection in city drop down driving the items available in state drop down) you can utilise the `change` event triggered upon selection of an item from city drop down.

Disable StateDropDown during initialisation and provide an empty `dataSource`:

```
$('<input id="Statedropdown" data-text-field="Text" data-value-
    field="Value" data-bind="value:'+options.field+'" />')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendDropDownList({
         enable: false,
         autoBind: true,
         cascadeFrom: "Countrydropdown", 
         dataTextField="Text", 
         dataValueField="Value",
         dataSource: []             
     });
```

Hook up an `change` event to the `CountryDropDown` which will use an `AJAX` call to your controller function (`getstates`) providing the `id` of the country selected as a parameter:

```
$('<input id="Countrydropdown" data-text-field="Text" data-value-
    field="Value" data-bind="value:'+options.field+'" />')
        .appendTo(container)
            .kendDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataTextField="Text", 
            dataValueField="Value",
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport:{
                    read:{
                        url: "../mycontroller/Details",
                        method:"POST"
                    }
                }
            },
            change: function(e) {
                // extract item selected
                var item = this.dataItem();

                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "/yourController/getstates",        
                   data: JSON.stringify(item.ID), // ID of country selected
                   dataType: "json",
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   async: true,
                   success: function (response) { // response will contain listates returned from controller
                       var stateDropDown = $("#Statedropdown").data("kendoDropDownList")';
                       // changed to use another approach to set dataSource                           
                       var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                           data: response
                       });
                       stateDropDown.setDataSource(dataSource);
                   }
                });
            }
      });
```

Code is untested so you may need some tweaks on the `AJAX` call / if the drop down is being used within a grid (still don't know if it is or not), you may need to get the `stateDropDown` closest to the `countryDropDown` selected but this should get you on the right track.

**EDIT**

Changed the `success` method on the AJAX call to use the [`setDataSource`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-setDataSource) function. Note that you need to build the `dataSource` using your `response` prior to assigning to the kendo drop down.

Comment: Actually in the example you have coated. They are using arrays and 
within Model array there is a Foreign Key of Brand so that cascade Tag is working on it.
In my case I am passing only Text and ID from my getcities method.

Comment: Please see updated answer as an alternative to `cascading` if this is not feasible in your situation.

Comment: I have added the same code you have posted above. But again SateDropdownList is not populating. 
Success function is working fine. But stateDropDown is not receiving the Object "response". I have checked the browser console.
there is an error "stateDropDown.datasource is undefined"

Comment: Check my edit, not sure if you can assign `dataSource.data` directly onto a drop down list, so try using `setDataSource` method instead.

Comment: Excellent! Happy to help @Ali